# Link for a variable with PHP to download a link on my MySQL database

Tags: php, download

I have files on my MySQL database and I want to create a link (for my variable $files) to download these files.

```
$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT name, filename, filepath FROM documents");
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
   $files=$donnees['filename'];

   // [Doing some work here...]

   if (preg_match($word,$line)) {
        echo "<center>Word ".$word." found in the file ".$files."</center>";    
   }
}
```

Comment: I know that French people are really proud of their language, but if you are asking for help, please, please, REALLY PLEASE... use English, especially in code.

Comment: I'm not proud of my language :P I have edited my code, sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filepath is a local path (like `/var/www/uploads/myfile.txt`), you'll need to make a new PHP page to allow the user to download a file. So there are two steps:

1. Write the download URL in your current loop
2. Create a new page of download

Your loop modified:

```
$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT name, filename, filepath FROM documents");
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
$files=$donnees['filename'];
// ... stuff here ...
if (preg_match($word,$line)) {

     echo "<center>Word ".$word." found in the file <a href=\"download.php?file=".$filepath."\">".$files."</a></center>";

}
```

In download.php:

```
<?php
$file=$_GET['file'];

if (($file != "") && (file_exists("./" . basename($file)))) // add some checks to avoid the download of critical files...
{
    $size = filesize("./" . basename($file));
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"" . basename($file) . "\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\"");
    readfile("./" . basename($file));
    exit();
}
?>
```